# Remote desktop sessions - can you be active and idle at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

When someone has a state of 'active' and an idle time, does that mean that they are logged into the remote desktop, but haven't used it for 'n' minutes, where 'n' is the idle time?

I've been researching the states online, and haven't found this described well anywhere.

If so, the terminology lends itself to confusion because the session can be 'active' and 'idle' at the same time.

Comment: Though not really defining the terms, we can use this (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx) to mean that active is any RDP session, and idle is any active RDP session that has no user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Remote Desktop Services allows users to disconnect from a remote session without logging off and ending the session. When a session is in a disconnected state, running programs are kept active even though the user is no longer actively connected.

**Active session limit**
Specify the maximum amount of time that the user's Remote Desktop Services session can be active before the session is automatically disconnected or ended.
The user receives a warning two minutes before the Remote Desktop Services session is disconnected or ended, which allows the user to save open files and close programs.

**Idle session limit**
Specify the maximum amount of time that an active Remote Desktop Services session can be idle (without user input) before the session is automatically disconnected or ended.
The user receives a warning two minutes before the session is disconnected or ended, which allows the user to press a key or move the mouse to keep the session active

So yes users can be idle and active at the same as active session is a session without the the user being connected. [More info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx)

Comment: So 'active' and 'idle' time of 5, that means the user is logged on but hasn't moved the mouse/keyboard in the remote desktop session for 5 minutes?

Comment: Correct, that is exactly how the idle time is defined